# Convert country name to int in panda

Tags: python, pandas, object, int

```
pd.Series(Confirmed_df["Country/Region"]).convert_objects(convert_numeric= True)
```

FutureWarning: convert_objects is deprecated.  To re-infer data dtypes for object columns, use Series.infer_objects()
For all other conversions use the data-type specific converters pd.to_datetime, pd.to_timedelta and pd.to_numeric.
  after removing the cwd from sys.path.

the output :

```
0                 Afghanistan
1                     Albania
2                     Algeria
3                     Andorra
4                      Angola
5         Antigua and Barbuda
6                   Argentina
7                     Armenia
8                   Australia
9                   Australia
10                  Australia
11                  Australia
12                  Australia
13                  Australia
14                  Australia
15                  Australia
16                    Austria
17                 Azerbaijan
18                    Bahamas
19                    Bahrain
20                 Bangladesh
21                   Barbados
22                    Belarus
23                    Belgium
24                      Benin
25                     Bhutan
26                    Bolivia
27     Bosnia and Herzegovin
```

but it is still (object) I want to convert to int type.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: I want to convert the type from object to int

Comment: You cannot convert strings to int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IICU:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Country':['Antigua and Barbuda','Argentina','Kenya']})
codes,uniques=pd.factorize(df.Country)
codes
```

Obviously, to convert to column

```
df['x']=pd.Series(codes)
df
```

Comment: I thought you wanted to code them. I will leave my answer anyway. Maybe provide more info on expected output